# MySQL: Max Date(), Summarizing Values of Last Date for Separate Columns

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to summarize by Company_Name the last values of Date_Time for each every Employees (Sum) and QA_Score (Average) of each respective Wing_Name with this dataset:

```
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| Company_Name | Wing_Name |    Date_Time     | Employees | QA_Score |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:00 |        82 | 3.5      |
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:01 |        83 | 3.6      |
| Company A    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 13:02 |        84 | 3.7      |
| Company A    | Wing B    | 06/08/2018 13:00 |        50 | 4.1      |
| Company A    | Wing B    | 06/08/2018 13:01 |        51 | 4.2      |
| Company A    | Wing B    | 06/08/2018 13:02 |        52 | 4.3      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:00 |        82 | 3.6      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:01 |        85 | 3.7      |
| Company B    | Wing A    | 06/08/2018 14:02 |        88 | 3.8      |
+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+----------+
```

The desired output is:

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Company_Name | Employees | QA_Score |
+--------------+-----------+----------+
| Company A    |       136 | 4        |
| Company B    |        88 | 3.8      |
+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

I've been successful in using the following code to display the last result of Date_Time by Wing_Name but cannot for the life of me figure it out for Company_Name, while leaving Wing_Name out of the output.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (Wing_Name, Date_Time) IN
(SELECT Wing_Name, MAX(Date_Time) Date_Time FROM table GROUP BY Wing_Name)
AND `Company_Name` = "Company A";
```

The desired output should now be the sum of Employees for Company_Name through results of every Wing_name, along with the Average of QA_Score for those respective Wing_Name but summarized under Company_Name

The desired output follows this logic:

- Last Date_Time value for Employees for Company A And Wing A was 84.
- Last Date_Time value for Employees for Company A and Wing B was 52.
- Company A has 84+52 Employees (136) as of the last Date_Time
  retrieval.
- Last Date_Time value for QA_Score for Company A and Wing A was 3.7.
- Last Date_time value for QA_Score for Company A and Wing B was 4.3.
- Company A Average QA_Score is 4.0
- Company B Number of Employees is 88
- Company B Average QA_Score 3.8

This must be something simple that I am missing? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by both `company_name` and `wing_name` in the subquery, then group the main query by just `company_name` to combine the rows that were selected.

```
SELECT t1.company_name, SUM(t1.employees) AS employees, AVG(t1.qa_score) AS qa_score
FROM table AS t1
JOIN (SELECT company_name, wing_name, MAX(date_time) AS maxtime
      FROM table
      GROUP BY company_name, wing_name) AS t2
ON t1.company_name = t2.company_name AND t1.wing_name = t2.wing_name AND t1.date_time = t2.maxtime
GROUP BY t1.company_name
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb4dcf/1)